# What if all mention contact points go down after successful connection to the cluster?

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I have 3 node Cassandra cluster.I have put only one contact point as the part of the initialization. What will happen if it goes down after successful connection to the cluster. I still have 2 more running nodes, will it caters the future request???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the contact points are used only for setting up initial connection. After that, driver will discover the other nodes in the cluster, and if first node goes down, then it will use other nodes. Here is excerpt from [Java driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/control_connection/), Python driver should work similarly:

> When the driver starts, the control connection is established to the first contacted node. If that node goes down, a reconnection is started to find another node; it is governed by the same policy as regular connections and tries the nodes according to a query plan from the load balancing policy.